# Unable to send files over 1 MB via FTP on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, powershell, batch-file

I tried to send multiple files via FTP commands using simple batch script. It works fine when the file size is less than 1 MB but when the file is larger than 1 MB I get the following error log.

#### Files to be sent:

```
    H:\dir\file1.xls         (aprox 500KB)
    H:\dir\file2.xls"        (aprox 500KB)
    H:\dir\folder\file3.xls" (aprox 1500KB) NOT SENT
    H:\dir\folder\file4.xls" (aprox 1500KB) NOT SENT
```

#### logs.txt:

```
    Conectado a www.mysite.com.
    220 ProFTPD 1.3.4a Server (ProFTPD Server) [::ffff:200.11.111.111]
    Usuario (mysite.com:(none)): 
    331 Password required for user@mysite.com

    230 User user@mysite.com logged in
    ftp> bin
    200 Type set to I
    ftp> put "H:\dir\file1.xls"
    200 PORT command successful
    150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file1.xls
    226 Transfer complete
    ftp: 618496 bytes enviados en 3,28 segundos 188,51 a KB/s.

    ftp> put "H:\dir\file2.xls"
    200 PORT command successful
    150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file2.xls
    226 Transfer complete
    ftp: 37888 bytes enviados en 0,00 segundos 37888000,00 a KB/s.

    ftp> put "H:\dir\folder\file3.xls"
    200 PORT command successful
    ftp> Desconectado.

    ftp> put "H:\dir\folder\file4.xls"
    quit
```

#### send.bat

```
   ftp -s:comandosftp.txt ftp.mysite.com > logs.txt
```

#### comandosftp.txt

```
   user@mysite.com
   password
   bin
   put "H:\dir\file1.xls"
   put "H:\dir\file2.xls"
   put "H:\dir\folder\file3.xls"
   put "H:\dir\folder\file4.xls"
   quit
```

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Have you tried the same batch file a second time? Does it fail in the same place every time?

Comment: Only test in same batch, y will try

Comment: Yes in separate batch send. Now i can not send all into one Batch file?

Comment: Would you please change the order of the files sent to see if you can just send two files regardless the file size?

Comment: Is there any storage quota imposed on server side?

Comment: It seems that the problem already starts with the second file. It seems that there is only transferred 37kB. What is the real size of the second file (file2.xls / farmacia.xls)? You can also try to perform the commands from comandosftp.txt by hand to see if you get the same error. I'm wondering if the FTP client thinks that the data connection from the first file upload is still open, when it sends the second put command, but the server then closes the data connection just as the data transfer begins. Perhaps a network trace (Wireshark) can show if that is the case.

Comment: Sorry "farmacia.xls" should be "file1.xls" i put a generic name, forgotting change thtat. I solve temporary separate proccess on each file and adding the line "disconnect and quit" but i not sure if sending more Kbs will appears error again